# How to recast a struct to a u32?

Tags: c

In the API I am calling, it has an 'extenededmode' field which allows me to pass my user specific extension:

```
  750 struct my_struct {
  751     __u32          field1;   
  752     __u32          field2;   
  753     __u32          field3;
  754     __u32          extendedmode; /* user extension */
  755     __u32              field4; 
  756     __u32          reserved[4];
  757 };
```

So I want to uses that field to put my struct there.

```
struct my_ext {
   _8  ext1;
   _8  ext2;
   _16 ext3;
}
```

so how can I put my_ext (which has the size of u32) to place it at extendedmode of my_struct?

Thank you.

Comment: What will the user do with `extendedmode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or create a union:

```
union my_ext {
    _32 value;
    struct my_ext {
       _8  ext1;
       _8  ext2;
       _16 ext3;
    };
}

my_struct my = ...;
my_ext ext = ...;
ext.ext1 = ...;
ext.ext2 = ...;
ext.ext3 = ...;
my.extendedmode = ext.value;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In the case of the following order of the fields:
  extendedmode     bit31-bit16  bit15-bit8 bit7-bit0
                   |            |          |
  my_ext           _16 ext3     _8 ext2    _8 ext1
```

I think that @pat is right, but it can only be used in a big endian processor.

For a little endian processor, the union might be written like this:

```
union my_ext {
    _32 value;
    struct my_ext {
       _16 ext3;
       _8  ext2;
       _8  ext1;
    };
}
```

Comment: why does the order of the fields matter?  Only if you intended to write a value on a big-endian machine, and read it on a little-endian machine (or vice-versa) would it matter.  As long as you write and read it on the same machine, the order shouldn't matter.

Comment: I tested in an Intel PC and I am sure that the order of the fields does matter. For example, my_ext's address was 0x2EFD20, it means that ext1(value:0x01) was in 0x2EFD20, ext2(value:0x02) was in 0x2EFD21 and ex3(value:0x0304) was in 0x2EFD22, then I got 0x03040201 via ext.value.

Comment: If the address of a struct is reversed in a big-endian(when my_ext's address is 0x2EFD20, ext1 will be in 0x2EFD23, ext2 will be in 0x2EFD22 and ex3 will be in 0x2EFD20), the order of the fields does not matter. I have not a big-endian machine, so I can not have a test.

Comment: The relative addresses of the fields will be the same regardless of endianess. In your example, ext3 will be at the lowest address, and ext1 will be at the highest address. The only difference is that when accessing a multi-byte field, a big-endian machine will put the most significant bits at the lowest address, and a little-endian machine will put the least significant bits at the lowest address.  The 32-bit packed result will appear different, but that's OK because it is always constructed and deconstructed consistently by the compiler

Comment: Reversing the order of the fields is unnecessary, and still won't make the 32-bit value appear the same because the individual bytes within the 16-bit subfield will still appear reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `memcpy` the value into the `extendedmode` slot?

```
my_struct my = ...;
my_ext ext = ...;
memcpy(&my.extendedmode, &ext, sizeof(ext));
```

Answer (score 0):

You also could implement your own pack and unpack functions for `struct my_ext`. For example,

```
__u32 pack(struct my_ext ext) {
    return (ext.ext1 << 24) | (ext.ext2 << 16) | ext.ext3;
}

struct my_ext unpack(__u32 ext_val) {
    struct my_ext ext;
    ext.ext1 = (ext_val >> 24) & 0xFF;
    ext.ext2 = (ext_val >> 16) & 0xFF;
    ext.ext3 = ext_val & 0xFFFF;
    return ext;
}
```

Comment: That's essentially what the `union` does, but with more syntax.  This would definitely be the way to go if you cared about exactly how the fields were packed (because you intended to transmit them in a packet to another machine for instance), but where you don't really care, why not let the compiler pick a packing for you.

Comment: @pat Agreed. I am just try to offer another option.